Unity and Horizontal Layout Boxes - Not Setting Children in Correct Position
I am encountering an issue with Unity and Horizontal Layout Groups.
I have a number of items in the horizontal layout group. Every time I try to expand one of these items by script, it shifts everything over to the left.
Any button (children of the horizontal layout group) can be used "select" the tab in the GUI, causing the gameobject to expand in size to show the name of the tab. The first time it's clicked, it shifts all the children of the horizontal layout group to the left. The second time, it places them back to where they are supposed to be.
Has anyone experienced this problem before?
I have tried ensuring that all rectransforms from the children to the end canvas are seated correctly, which they all are. I have tried calling the tab selection script twice instead of clicking it twice, and that doesn't work. I have tried replacing all the items in the horizontal layout group gameobject, but this doesn't work.
I have recently tried calling the tab selection function twice, waiting for a frame change in between. This seems to work but isn't an elegant solution.

When you add or remove anything to and from a layout grounp you need to rebuild the layout as the number of items under the Rect Transform has changed.
Hopefully Unity will automate it someday in future. For now you can call
            LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(gameObjectWithRectTransform);

So every time you add or remove an item(or expand any child) under your layout group, call the above method with reference of Rect Transform with Layout Group component.
I believe I missed few more details that could help you or anyone else that finds this in future.
When instantiating a gameobject under a layout group, Unity tends to set their position and scale to some random value(not sure where these values come from). So you have to reset their transform position and scale after instantiating.
GameObject newItem = Instantiate(itemPrefab);

newItem.transform.SetParent(itemsHolder);

newItem.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

newItem.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(referenceToItemsHolderLayoutGroup);

For more information check: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate.html

Thank you so much! I didn't find this in any of the tutorials I was using when I first started, so I've been doing without.
